# How to make a video which can play/loop infinite times using FFMPEG command in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Here are some details: I have a main video and I want a view (gif or video) on it which plays infinite times till video ends. Here is my current code snippet which executes successfully which plays my overlay video one time only.

```
cmd = new String[]{"-y", "-i", String.valueOf(mVideoPath), "-i", tempVideoPath, "-filter_complex", overlay.toString(), "-codec:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", String.valueOf(file)};
```

Where `tempVideoPath` is the path of my overlay video.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-stream_loop` input option:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i loop.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Can you give the code snippet for android java version? I have tried your suggestion as below but it went in failure.

`cmd = new String[]{"-y", "-i", String.valueOf(mVideoPath), "-stream_loop", "-1", "-i",tempVideoPaths.get(0), "-filter_complex", " [0][1]overlay=shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map 0:a?", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-c:a", "copy", "-movflags", "+faststart", String.valueOf(file)};`

Comment: @MitShah I don't know anything about android java, and without any errors provided I can only guess that `"-i",tempVideoPaths.get(0),` should be `"-i", tempVideoPaths.get(0),` (there is missing space).